# Using accessors in Obj-C -- is it just semantics?

Tags: objective-c, properties, instance-variables, accessor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use properties or direct reference when accessing instance variables internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753130/should-i-use-properties-or-direct-reference-when-accessing-instance-variables-in)

I have always wondered: is there any particular reason always to use or not use accessor methods (either square brackets or dot notation)? Whenever I synthesize properties, I do so like this...

```
@synthesize aProperty = _aProperty;
```

And then throughout my code I always use `self.aProperty` instead of `_aProperty`.

It seems to me logical to always use the accessors. However, in most sample/tutorial code, authors seem to be somewhat inconsistent with this usage, sometimes `self.aProperty`, sometimes `_aProperty`, and sometimes even just `aProperty` (without having set the alias in synthesize). Can anyone explain why it would or would not be advisable to always use the accessors, or in which cases would it be not advisable?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no situation in which its not advisable to use accessors.  Its all just semantics; using accessors means you can reuse those variable names (aProperty) if you like, which can be nice in custom setters.  However, it also means that you keep scope in mind and use self.aProperty.

When I teach a new junior developer, I have them use accessors as it forces them to keep scope in mind.

But I'm more than guilty myself of not bothering with them, just synthesizing the variable and accessing it directly (without using self).

-- Update due to comments --

I took the question as a higher-level question, however it is definitely worth noting on a programmatic basis that the comments below are absolutely, 100% correct, and I do apologize for not clarifying this.

Accessors should **never** be used in constructors and de-constructors, as these subclasses may not be stable and this can cause crashes.

Comment: You should use the ivar directly during deallocation and initialization, as subclasses may override the property's methods to do things your class doesn't expect.

Comment: There's a very important situation when you shouldn't use accessors: during object construction and destruction, i.e., in `init...` and `dealloc`.

Comment: @Geekswordsman Thanks. I should have clarified that I was not talking about initialization. However, with ARC we are no longer dealloc-ing. So, init using the ivar (_aProperty) but release by setting to nil (self.aProperty = nil), e.g., in viewDidUnload. Right?

Comment: You can set them to nil if you want, but not necessary.  The main thing to do is make sure that any observers are removed as ARC doesn't take care of those.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line as I've always heard it: you should always use the synthesized getter and setter. However, there are times when you need to access the variable directly, especially when you may override the synthesized getter or setter to return/set some processed data but need to also access the raw data from inside the class.

Example:

```
@synthesize firstName = _firstName;
```

Say in this example you wanted to use the default setter but you wanted to override the getter to always return a normalized version of the first name (sorry, I know its weird but I can think of a better example off the top of my head). So you can do something like this.

```
- (NSString*)getFirstName {
    return [_firstName lowercaseString];
}
```

Anytime that you use [self firstName] or self.firstName you will access the variable through the getter and get back a lowercase version. However, if you needed to still access the raw variable you could use _firstName to directly access it.